# SELECT MAX field value OR zero value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I have table `user_groups` and I need to select maximal `int` value of field `time` or `0` if any `user_group` entity has `0` in `time` field.

Something like this:

```
SELECT time FROM user_groups
WHERE
IF (time == 0) THEN time = 0
ELSE MAX(time)
```

I need multiplatform solution.


**UPDATED:**


I'm using `mysql`.

In this case:

```
id | time |
1  |  5   |
2  |  6   |
```

I'm expecting `6`.

In this case:

```
id | time |
3  |  5   |
4  |  6   |
5  |  0   |
```

I'm expecting `0`

Comment: Which is your database SQL server, Oracle, MySql etc. Give some sample data and expected output.

Comment: So with the records time=10, time=20 and time=30 you want to show 30 (the maximum time), but with records time=10, time=20 and time=0 you want to show 0, because a record with time=0 exists? Yes?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `time` can only be `0` or positive?

Comment: @cnaize Could you write more datails? What is in this table? What 'time' column mean and why you need such query? Just for my curiosity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution usues abs function to cover also negative time case:

```
SELECT case when min(abs(time)) = 0 then 0 else max(time) end FROM user_groups;
```

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution for all dbms that support ABS. (I think most dbms do. MySQL does.) ABS is a standard SQL function as of SQL2003, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4):

How about using case

```
SELECT case when min(time) = 0 then 0 else max(time) end FROM user_groups;
```

or if time could be < 0 but only time 0 or more should be considered then adding a where clause can help

```
SELECT case when min(time) = 0 then 0 else max(time) end FROM user_groups where time >= 0;
```

Comment: This assumes that `time` cannot be negative, which may or may not be a safe assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes you are right. I have edited my answer to include a where clause

Comment: If time can be negative, it is not a good solution to exclude such records from the evaluation. If there are only two records, with time = -1 and time = -2, then result should be -1, but your query would result in NULL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner on second thought the first query without the where the clause will work anyway, because in case of negative value min(time) will not = 0, thus will always fall back to the else clause and return -1 based on your example

Comment: And on third thought the first query would result in 1 for time = -1 , time = 0, and time = 1, instead of 0 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Check if at least one record's time is zero. Depending on the result show 0 or max(time)

```
select 
  case when max(case when time = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then 0 else max(time) end
from user_groups;
```

EDIT: You have added the MySQL tag to your request. MySQL knows a BOOLEAN data type where TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0. So you can write the above as:

```
select 
  case when max(time = 0) then 0 else max(time) end
from user_groups;
```

Comment: I think you have error in your second example. It should be max(time)=0, instead of max(time=0)

Comment: @rtruszk: No. `max(time=0)` means: Check each record for time = 0. Each match is TRUE, which is 1. Each mismatch is FALSE, which is 0. The maximum is either 1 = TRUE in case there is at least one match, or 0 = FALSE in case there is none.

Comment: It's a clever solution. It's tricky and I interpreted it wrongly first time.

Comment: @rtruszk: Well, this treatment of boolean expressions is really something special in MySQL. Thus it is very readable for a MySQL person, but for others it is confusing at first, because the knowledge on how MySQL treats boolean expressions is needed.